# How do I login to my Instagram account without a security code that is sent to my stolen phone

Tags: instagram

I was wondering how do I regain access to my instagram account without having to put in a security/verification code as my phone just got stolen and I'm trying to gain access to contact family and friends.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming it's texted? Contact your phone company and get the current sim deactivated, then get a new one. Your number isn't lost.

Of it's through an app then they should have other recovery options but also would have given backup codes, no?